# Unable to Load data using IBM DB2 Load tool

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to Load a certain data set for a course but it keeps failing and mentions that I do not have the necessary authorization

```
Error for batch element #1: The statement failed because the authorization ID does not have the required authorization or privilege to perform the operation. Authorization ID: "HLZ16072". Operation: "CREATE TABLE". Object: "DB2INST1.SCHOOL".. SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501, DRIVER=4.26.14
```

Number of occurrences: 1

The error changes to the table is absent when I use error schema, I understand I need to give access using [DATAACCESS authority](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0053934.html), but I still can't figure out how to give myself the required permissions to Load the CSV file.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DOng.png)

The above is the result of :
SELECT GRANTEE, GRANTEETYPE, SECURITYADMAUTH, DATAACCESSAUTH FROM SYSCAT.DBAUTH WHERE 'Y' IN (SECURITYADMAUTH, DATAACCESSAUTH)

Comment: Please, edit your question with the result of `SELECT GRANTEE, GRANTEETYPE, SECURITYADMAUTH, DATAACCESSAUTH FROM SYSCAT.DBAUTH WHERE 'Y' IN (SECURITYADMAUTH, DATAACCESSAUTH)`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems, that your user `HLZ16072` doesn't have a privilege to create tables in the `DB2INST1` schema, and you can't get the information about the user who may grant you such an ability (RCAC on the system catalog tables?).
So, you should either find your database admin and ask him/her on such an ability to grant you the corresponding privileges, or try to understand, which schemas you are allowed to create your tables in. You should try to use the schema `HLZ16072` instead of `DB2INST1`, which is likely the right schema for you. Or try to run the following select statement to find such schemas.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (P.OBJECTSCHEMA) AS SCHEMA 
--P.PRIVILEGE, P.OBJECTTYPE, P.OBJECTSCHEMA, P.OBJECTNAME, U.AUTHID, U.AUTHIDTYPE
FROM SYSIBMADM.PRIVILEGES P
CROSS JOIN TABLE(VALUES 'HLZ16072') A (AUTHID)
JOIN TABLE 
(
SELECT GROUP, 'G' FROM table(AUTH_LIST_GROUPS_FOR_AUTHID(A.AUTHID))
  UNION ALL
select ROLENAME, 'R' from table(AUTH_LIST_ROLES_FOR_AUTHID(A.AUTHID, 'U'))
  UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE(VALUES ('PUBLIC', 'G'), (A.AUTHID, 'U')) T (AUTHID, AUTHIDTYPE)
) U (AUTHID, AUTHIDTYPE) ON U.AUTHID=P.AUTHID AND U.AUTHIDTYPE=P.AUTHIDTYPE
WHERE P.PRIVILEGE='CREATEIN';
```

Comment: Hello, The DB2 instance is created by me, so shouldn't I by default have the necessary permissions to edit it as required (Wouldn't that make me itself the admin).The output of te above code is (DSJOBMGR
DSSCHED
DSSHSV1
DSWEB
DSWEBSECURITY)                                                                                                                    So my understanding is that that I can use any of the below schemas to LOAD a CSV as data set? But I do not see any of the above-mentioned Schemas when I use the LOAD tool.

Comment: If you created the instance, then login with the `db2inst1` user and grant necessary privileges to `HLZ16072`. You may read about such a privileges in the description of the `CREATE TABLE` in the Knowledge Center.